# Integrating django-tinymce and django-filebrowser

Tags: django, django-tinymce, django-filebrowser

I'm writing small django app which allows user to post messages with tinymce editor, installed with django-tinymce. Everything works fine, but when i'm trying to add django-filebrowser to install apps,tinymce widget disappears from post form. I have installed grappelli and PIL library. It works from /admin/filebrowser/browse. I can upload files,but thumbnails doesn't show up. Django-filebrowser cannot pass test:

```
python2.6 manage.py test filebrowser 
Creating Test for the FileBrowser site: filebrowser 
Creating test database for alias 'default'... 
..................uploads/tmp_test_0/testimage_medium.jpg 
FRemoving left-over tmp dir: uploads/tmp_test_0 
====================================================================== 
FAIL: runTest (filebrowser.tests.sites.TestSite_filebrowser) 
---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/filebrowser/tests/ 
sites.py", line 233, in runTest 
    test_detail(self) 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/filebrowser/tests/ 
sites.py", line 140, in test_detail 
    test.assertTrue(test.site.storage.exists(path)) 
AssertionError: False is not True 
---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
Ran 19 tests in 1.114s 
FAILED (failures=1) 
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

I'm using filebroswer 3.41, django-tinymce 1.5.1b2, PIL 1.1.7, grappelli 2.3.7

My seetings:

```
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) 
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'media/') 
MEDIA_URL = '/media/' 
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'static/') 
STATIC_URL = '/static/' 
TINYMCE_JS_URL = STATIC_URL + 'tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js' 
TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {'theme': "advanced", } 
TINYMCE_FILEBROWSER = True 
# Filebrowser 
FILEBROWSER_MEDIA_ROOT = MEDIA_ROOT 
FILEBROWSER_MEDIA_URL = MEDIA_URL 
FILEBROWSER_STATIC_ROOT = STATIC_ROOT 
FILEBROWSER_STATIC_URL = STATIC_URL 
URL_FILEBROWSER_MEDIA = STATIC_URL + 'filebrowser/' 
PATH_FILEBROWSER_MEDIA = STATIC_ROOT + 'filebrowser/' 
URL_TINYMCE = STATIC_URL + 'tiny_mce/' 
PATH_TINYMCE = STATIC_ROOT + 'tiny_mce/'
```

tinymce files ar in /mainprojectfolder/static/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js

urls.py:

```
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)), 
    url(r'^admin/filebrowser/', include(site.urls)), name='tinymce-filebrowser'), 
    (r'baza/', include('projekt.baza.urls')), 
    (r'^grappelli/', include('grappelli.urls')), 
    (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT, 'show_indexes':True}),
    (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes':True}),
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: I don't see the tinymce url pattern in your urls.py...(r'^tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),

Comment: cant belive i missed it. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. I hate when I do stuff like that :)

Comment: Is there a way to make djnago-filebrowser work out of admin interface, or if there is a django app that allows regular users uploading images using tinymce?

Comment: I'm not, I haven't looked at the Filebrowser API, but there's no reason you couldn't just have a standard Django model with an image or file field that has the upload_to parameter of the field set to the same directory as Fielbrowser.